# Linq, lambda - which statement is faster?

Tags: linq, performance, lambda

I was wondering which expression is faster and which one is preferred:

```
myList.Select(a => a.Property)
      .Where(a => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(a))

myList.Where(a => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Property))
      .Select(a => a.Property)
```

and of course why?

Generally my question is: should I use `Where` followed by `Select` or `Select` followed by `Where`?

Comment: They are not the same, and neither compiles. The second one should be `a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Property)`

Comment: fixed code to what it almost certainly should have been.

Comment: @Eamon - almost, I took out an extra `a =>`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one can know, you must measure.  Consider a list of 50 items, with 40 items meeting the filter criteria.

Project then filter, this approach minimizes the number of accesses to a.Property.  100 anonymous method invocations and 50 property accesses.

```
myList
   .Select(a => a.Property)
   .Where(a => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
```

Filter then project, this approach minimizes the number of calls to anonymous methods.  90 anonymous method invocations and 90 property accesses.

```
myList
   .Where(a => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Property))
   .Select(a => a.Property)
```

Since we don't know the costs of your property's implementation vs the costs of an anonymous method invocation, there's no way to reason about the performance difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the second one, where you filter the data first (using `Where`) and then select (using `Select`) what data you want.

Depending on the data you are filtering performance may vary, but I feel the second one is more in flow.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Linq provider.

For example in Linq2Sql both statements are the same since thwy will generate the same SQL against the database.

In Linq2Objects it may perform diferently.

Comment: Hello, guy who ,for some reason, can't believe two person can write the same answer (specially if they seem to be correct).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't much matter.  In cases such as the above, where the remainder of the "query" only references the projected data, you may as well project first and then filter.

Note that it's not the case that filtering first is necessarily faster; by calling `Select` first you will be executing fewer property accessors - but the difference is likely to be minor either way.

If you're going to write more complex queries, I suggest writing reducing the scope of the data as quickly as you can, which in this case means writing the `Select` before the `Where`: that results in shorter code which is more readable in longer queries: after all, by focusing only on the relevant bits (here strings) the reader can ignore the more complex objects containing them in the rest of the query.  This advantage is fairly pointless for such a small query, however.